# Trying to grab specific HTML for web scrape

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the following url: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201809060phi.htm

Specifically, I want info from the "Passing, Rushing, & Receiving" table. I have the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# assigning url
my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201809060phi.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
raw_page = uReq(my_url)
page_html = raw_page.read()
raw_page.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

# assign variable to stat table
stat_table = page_soup.find ("div",{"id":"all_player_offense"})
inner_table = stat_table.findAll("tr")
print(len(inner_table)
```

It should be printing the number of player rows in that table. The output I get from this is 0 instead of what I expected, 17.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the parent `div` to the table instead of the table itself. Double check the HTML markup of the page and you'll find the id of the table.

Also note that the table uses a `tbody` instead of immediately listing the rows, so you'll have to account for that as well.